# Accessing Database Schema Information from Groovy

Tags: database, groovy, database-schema

I'm trying to wrap some Groovy test around code that modifies a schema. What's the idiomatic Groovy approach towards getting information about a database schema (e.g. determining the names & types of columns on a table and the primary key)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access metaData on the entire database by doing:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB", "uid", "pwd", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
def metadata = sql.connection.metaData
```

Thus will give you an instance of [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) to play with